# css @media does not target specific device iPhone 7 plus

Tags: css, iphone, landscape

I am trying to target only the landscape mode of iPhone 7 plus but any combination of values does not seem to work. Attached is a codepen. Could somebody please make this work? :) . [Codepen demo link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXewOm)

```
   .box {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: coral;
}

@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 1080px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1920px)  
    and (orientation :landscape) 
    and (min-resolution: 401dpi)
    and (device-aspect-ratio:16/9)
/*     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) */
{  
  .box {
    background-color: blue; 
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<main><div class="box"></div></main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix!! It only targeted iPhone 7 plus landscape mode and not portrait mode!!

```
   .box {
      height: 30vh;
      width: 20vw;
      background-color: coral;
    }

        /* iPhone 7+ Landscape */
                @media only screen
                    and (min-device-width: 414px)
                    and (max-device-width: 736px)
                    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
                    and (orientation: landscape)
                    and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
            {  
              .box {
                background-color: blue; 
              }
            }

<!-- HTML -->
    <main><div class="box"></div></main>
```

[Working demo here: plz test on iPhone 7 plus](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjbpYo)

Answer (score 1):

Try this media query:

```
/* iPhone 7+ Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 
  ...
}
```

Working Snippet (Please try to run this on iPhone 7+):

```css
.box {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: coral;
}


/* iPhone 7+ Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) {  
  .box {
    background-color: blue; 
  }
}
```

```html
<main><div class="box"></div></main>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @saurav, this one also affects 7 plus portrait for some reason, I only need landscape style to change. The expectation is for the box to remain coral on iPhone 7 plus portrait and change to blue on landscape mode.

Comment: @witty2017 Are you sure you've included orientation attribute to media query? This should work, as I don't have any working device right now. Please let me know.

Comment: @witty2017 Try to run the above snippet on iPhone 7+ landscape mode.

Comment: yes I have included orientation, it should work ideally, but I am testing the codepen on my device and see blue box in both orientations.

Comment: @witty2017 I would recommend you to try incorporating this into the actual code instead of testing it on codepen or any other editor.

Comment: umm well been trying this fix in the code since 48 hours now..decided to go codepen way because behaviors were weird with any combination of media properties. I have tried ur earlier recommendation in code as well.